# Precisely determine how far a finger has moved in Android during ACTION_MOVE

Tags: java, android, touch, gesture, touch-event

In my **onTouchEvent** method's **ACTION_MOVE** I'm attempting to find out how many pixels the users finger has moved during a touch gesture - this amount will be updated every frame and an object on the screen will be moved
by the same amount.

This is what I'm doing so far:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            movedByY = oldYPosition - event.getY();

            oldYPosition = event.getY();

}
```

I'm only really concerned with movement in the Y direction and the above seems fairly simple.

Once I've got the amount, I move my object by the same amount - something like this.

```
myObject.currentYPos -= movedByY;
```

This *kind of* works, however, it isn't precise enough.  When moving downwards, the finger gets slightly ahead of the object (object moves too slow) and when moving upwards, the object gets slightly ahead of the finger (object moves too fast).  The slower you move your finger, the bigger the discrepency.

Note I can't simply set the object's coordinates to match the finger because that's not what I'm trying to achieve.  If the user places a finger down on the screen and moves it, the object should *mimic* it's movements extactly but not 'jump to' where it is.

Let's say the object is at 100,100 and the user places their finger down at 600 x 586 and moves 100 pixels upwards, then the object should follow this path and end up at 100 x 0 - and as we're updating this every frame, at any given frame the amount the object as moved, should match the amount the finger has moved *exactly*.

I can't figure out why it's moving at a different speed to the finger.  Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly are you adding the difference to your object position? ie where are you calling this line? `myObject.currentYPos -= movedByY;`

Comment: @Antrromet, it's being called from my update() method which is called from my game loop (from onDrawFrame).  This is called 60 times per second.

Comment: Ok I think I know the problem. Try updating your sprite's position from on the `ACTION_MOVE` itself, ie call `myObject.currentYPos -= movedByY;` in `ACTION_MOVE` and check once.

Comment: I thought you might be onto something there @Antrromet as I was also thinking the same thing - ie  different threads updating values at different times etc... but I've just tried it and I get the same result :-(

Comment: There's a discrepancy because your calculating the displacement in `ACTION_MOVE` (in one place) and changing your sprite in `onDrawFrame()`(in other place). Both these methods are not in sync with each other. So to get the perfect matching between your finger and sprite, both the calculations should be made in the same place.

Comment: Yes @Antrromet but like I said, I've just tried it from ACTION_MOVE, but I get the same result.  It hasn't made any difference.

Comment: Hmm, am sorry I cant help you at the moment then, let me ponder it over for sometime!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71056/discussion-between-zippy-and-antrromet).

Comment: @Antrromet, yes, it was the fact I was calculating the 'movedByY' amount on the UI thread.  However, moving everything onto the UI Thread didn't yield the desirable result, so I simply took a snapshot of it in my GLRendering thread and it works great!!

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was something to do with multi threads

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around the problem by working out the movedByY value in my GLRendering thread (in my update() method).

So, in ACTION_MOVE -  I did this:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

        onTouchYCoord = event.getY();

}
```

And then in my logic update method, used that value to get the correct amount like so:

```
logicYCoord = (int) onTouchYCoord ;

movedByY = logicYCoord -oldYPosition;

oldYPosition = logicYCoord;
```

Then I update the sprite's position:

```
myObject.currentYPos += movedByY;
```

This works perfectly and the object stays with the finger.  Clearly, the problem was the fact that I was using a value from the UI Thread which was could have changed at any time.  This way, I'm guaranteed the value I'm using in my calculations stays consistent by taking a snapshot of it.